# Freebase MQL - date regular expression

Tags: freebase, mql

I'm trying to query freebase to find out all the people who were born in specific day of a year. That is all the people that were born on August 4th regardless to the year.

I tried two methods - trying to reflect certain date (example below) or querying for people with date_of_birth. I'm using regular expression something like:
"date_of_birth~=":"*08-04"

```
[{
  "/type/reflect/any_value": [{
    "link": {
      "master_property": {
        "name": "Date of birth"
      }
    },
    "type": "/type/datetime",
    "value~=": "*08-04"
  }],
  "name": null,
  "type": "/common/topic"
}]
```

I get the following error message:
"*08-04 is a JSON string, but the expected type is /type/datetime"

Is there anyway I can query regular expressions regarding dates?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using the [Freebase Search API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-overview) now like this:

```
filter=(all type:/common/topic /people/person/date_of_birth:-08-04)
```

[Try it](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=&indent=true&filter=%28all%20type:/common/topic%20/people/person/date_of_birth%3a-08-04%29)

As a bonus, the results are ranked by notability in Freebase so you get the most notable people born on that day.